# Wiring fan with Lights

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I just purchased a house and I am trying to install a ceiling fan with light.

I googled but it shows white, black, and green cables but I have yellow, purple, gray, and red wires. Now which wire goes to what with the fan.

I haven’t purchased the fan yet. This are the wires in the ceiling. Also this is in the Chicago, IL (USA)

Please help me here?

Thank you!

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Usually the instructions tell you which wire powers the light and  which powers the fan. Yellow, purple, gray, and red are not standard in the USA. Where did the fan come from and where in the world are you?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes at both the ceiling and the switch that controls that ceiling location?

Comment: What brand is it? Photo?

Comment: The wires are in the ceiling and have t purchased the ceiling fan yet. I also included the images in the original post. 

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks into the back of that ceiling box please? That'll show us how the wires are grouped together, which is rather important

Comment: I added the pictures for back of the ceiling box to the forum.

Comment: @JayGandhi -- how many wall switches are there in this room, and what do they control? (if you don't know, that's fine)

Comment: @JayGandhi -- also, can you tell where the nearest ceiling joists are?

Comment: What was originally installed at this box? Are you replacing a different ceiling fan? Was the box used for something else? Or was the box covered when you found it (nothing installed) and it looked like a good place for a fan?

Comment: Nothing was installed there. It just looked like a good place to install a fan